# Objective-c - Detect file download from UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, url, uiwebview, download

In safari, you might notice sometimes a file might open in safari, and sometimes the same type of file might automatically be downloaded to the computer. How could i achieve similar functionality form a UIWebView. I don't want to check the file types individual and then download because it could be a file with a extension i don't know of, or forgot to add, and then sometimes it should be opened in the UIWebView itself. I just don't know how to check if that file is meant to be downloaded automatically anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Try to compare the url file type with the list of file type the UIWebView can handle. For that list, you can refer to Technical [Q&A QA1630](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1630/_index.html)

Comment: well i cant tell the type, like if i type "PDF" in google and find a pdf and check the url, the end is .pdf, if i go to this particular file, it doesnt have a file extension, but in the one downloads app, after clicked it wont load a page, and it will show download menu and show its file extention and its fie name, mine will open up a google search with a wierd url search, random every time